# Iterate through array timer fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

EDIT: Below is the code I ended up with after much messing around.

This is a basic carousel that sets the styles for each slide automatically, gives each item a class you can use to control content with, has the option to pause on hover if needed, sets the background image using the data attribute on each div, and also works with multiple instances on the same page.

just need to call it by:
$('#divName,#divName,#divName').startTheCaro();

SOLUTION:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.startTheCaro = function() {

    return this.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var $thisChild = $this.children();

        var theTransitionSpeed = 500; // Transition Speed
        var theTransitionDelay = 3000; // Amount Of Time Slide Is Shown
        var pauseOnHover = true; // Pause The Slide When Hovered // true or false
        var thisImagePath = 'images/careers/'; // Background Image Path

        var thisSlide = 0;
        var thisSlideNum = 0;
        var hoverPause = false;
        var caroIsPlaying = false;
        var newSlideName = 'thisCaroSlide';
        var theSlidesTotal = $this.children().length-1;

        // Setup each slide
        $this.children().each(function() {
            var $tC = $(this);
            $tC.css('display', 'none');
            var thisDataBgPath = $tC.data('bg');
            // Set styles and classes
            $(this).addClass('thisCaroSlide' + thisSlideNum);
            $tC.css('position', 'absolute');
            $tC.css('top', '0');
            $tC.css('left', '0');
            $tC.css('background', 'url(' + thisImagePath + thisDataBgPath + ') no-repeat top center');
            $tC.css('background-position','center '+((topDist($(this))/$(window).height())*(-1*parAmount))+'px');
            thisSlideNum++;
        });

        var playTheCaro = function() {
            var getTheClass = ('.thisCaroSlide' + thisSlide);
            if (hoverPause == true) {
                // Pause on hover
            } else {
                if (thisSlide == theSlidesTotal) {
                    $this.find(getTheClass).fadeIn(theTransitionSpeed, function(){
                        $this.find('div:not(:first-child, :last-child)').css('display', 'none');
                        thisSlide++;
                    });
                } else if (thisSlide == (theSlidesTotal+1)) {
                    $this.find('.thisCaroSlide' + theSlidesTotal).fadeOut(theTransitionSpeed, function(){
                    });
                    thisSlide = 1;
                } else {
                    $this.find(getTheClass).fadeIn(theTransitionSpeed, function(){
                    });
                    thisSlide++;
                };
            };
        };
        playTheCaro();

        // Pause the Carousel on Hover
        var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(playTheCaro, theTransitionDelay);
        $this.hover(function() {
            if (pauseOnHover == true) {
                refreshIntervalId = clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                hoverPause = true;
            }
        }, function() {
            if (pauseOnHover == true) {
                refreshIntervalId = setInterval(playTheCaro, theTransitionDelay);
                hoverPause = false;
            }
        });

    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Fade it in inside the `.each`. `theCurrentSlide.delay(i*2000).fadeIn()`

Comment: So, I apologize if I don't understand the use case. So you will have (let's pretend 3) slideshows going on. Will only one image be present (which is why we want the delay)? Or is this a cascading down fade effect with all of the images fading in one by one down the page?

Comment: Sorry, It is just a basic carousel. Images positioned one on top of the other. image fades in on top of the last. They are using a parallax layout, and want the inbetween sections to be carousels)

Comment: So, essentially, 3 slideshows going on inside of 1 slideshow?

Comment: Thanks Nicholas ended up going a different route, but the help was much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
/* the recursion functions */
playTheCaro = function(selector, index, delay, interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log(index , selector.length);
    if(index >= selector.length ){
        return;
    }
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        /* the next element in  is $(selector[index]) so you can do what you like with it.*/
        $(selector[index]).fadeIn();
        index++
        playTheCaro(selector, index , delay,interval);
    }, delay);  
};

playTheCaro($('#some li'), 0, 2000);
```

You'll have to twick this to fit your needs ofcs

you can see an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/J73Fu/2/

Comment: Thanks ended up going a different route, but the help was much appreciated. I'll definitely use this in another project though.

Comment: I still can't vote, haven't reached the minimum rep yet haha! and I ended up coming up with my own answer updated OP...

Answer (score 0):

Target the `function` at the end of your `each` loop.
Use a `parameter` in your `start carousel` function to target `each` item that needs to fade.

...

```
        playTheCaro($tC);
    });

    playTheCaro = function(thisSlide) {
        setInterval(function() {
            thisSlide.fadeIn();
        }, 2000);
    };
```

...

#### Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8thVJ/

Comment: I'm trying to keep everything inside the function so I can have multiple instances at the same time.

Comment: Well, you are targeting an ID of `#caro`, so multiple instances wouldn't work in the first place :-P. So, you will have multiple slideshows on the same page?

Comment: Could you throw your HTML into a fiddle so I can see what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well the script isn't targeting car its the opposite way, so I can have multiple elements use the same script which is why I can't simply call the divs to fade. And yea, they want multiple slideshows on the same page =/

Comment: i added a fiddle to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Neta Meta's solution, just had to alter it a little bit.

```
playTheCaro = function(selector, index, delay, interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(index >= selector.length ){
            $('ul li:not(:first-child, :last-child)').css('display', 'none');
            $('ul li:last-child').fadeOut(300, function(){
                index = 0;
            });
        } else {
            $(selector[index]).fadeIn(300);
            index++
            playTheCaro(selector, index , delay,interval);
        }
    }, delay);  
};
$('#some li:first-child').css('display', 'block');
playTheCaro($('#some li'), 0, 2000);
```

Here is a FIDDLE 
http://jsfiddle.net/J73Fu/4/

Just have one more question... If you run through this, on the restart, the first slide doubles the delay. How can you set the delay just for the first iteration?